# Fancier Fancy Indexing in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

I am implementing color interpolation using a look-up-table (LUT) with NumPy. At one point I am using the 4 most significant bits of RGB values to choose corresponding CMYK values from a 17x17x17x4 LUT. Right now it looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np
rgb = np.random.randint(16, size=(3, 1000, 1000))
lut = np.random.randint(256, size=(17, 17, 17, 4))
cmyk = lut[rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]]
```

Here comes the first question... Is there no better way? It sort of seems natural that you could tell NumPy that the indices for `lut` are stored along axis 0 of `rgb`, without having to actually write it out. So is there anything like `cmyk = lut.fancier_take(rgb, axis=0)` in NumPy?

Furthermore, I am left with an array of shape `(1000, 1000, 4)`, so to be consistent with the input, I need to rotate it all around using a couple of `swapaxes`:

```
cmyk = cmyk.swapaxes(2, 1).swapaxes(1, 0).copy()
```

And I also need to add the copy statement, because if not the resulting array is not contiguous in memory, and that brings trouble later on.

Right now I am leaning towards rotating the LUT before the fancy indexing and then do something along the lines of:

```
swapped_lut = lut.swapaxes(2, 1).swapaxes(1, 0)
cmyk = swapped_lut[np.arange(4), rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]]
```

But again, it just does not seem right... There has to be a more elegant way to do this, right? Something like `cmyk = lut.even_fancier_take(rgb, in_axis=0, out_axis=0)`...

Comment: I followed Bi Rico's suggestion, with the reshaped `arange`, and while it worked nicely, I have found out that by converting the `lut` from its `(17, 17, 17, 4)` shape into `(4, 4913)` and then using `take` and my own version of `ravel_multi_index` to extract the values I want, things happen about x10 faster...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do the following if you swap `lut`, `np.arange(4)` will not work:

```
swapped_lut = np.rollaxis(lut, -1)
cmyk = swapped_lut[:, rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]].copy()
```

Or you can replace

```
cmyk = lut[rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]]
cmyk = cmyk.swapaxes(2, 1).swapaxes(1, 0).copy()
```

with:

```
cmyk = lut[tuple(rgb)]
cmyk = np.rollaxis(cmyk, -1).copy()
```

But to try and do it all in one step, ... Maybe:

```
rng = np.arange(4).reshape(4, 1, 1)
cmyk = lut[rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], rng]
```

That's not very readable at all is it?

Take a look at the answer to this question, [Numpy multi-dimensional array indexing swaps axis order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942747/numpy-multi-dimensional-array-indexing-swaps-axis-order). It does a good job of explaining how numpy broadcasts multiple arrays to get the output size. Here  you want to create indices into lut that broadcast to (4, 1000, 1000). Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: So broadcasting also happens when fancy-indexing... That's both brilliant and obvious once you know it! This sure looks like the answer I was looking for, but give me the weekend to figure out the details on my own before accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using `tuple` to force indexing rowwise, and `np.rollaxis` or `transpose` instead of `swapaxes`:

```
lut[tuple(rgb)].transpose(2, 0, 1).copy()
```

or

```
np.rollaxis(lut[tuple(rgb)], 2).copy()
```

To roll the axis first, use:

```
np.rollaxis(lut, -1)[(Ellipsis,) + tuple(rgb)]
```

Comment: It may be a bit uglier, but instead of using Ellipses in the last example np.arange(4).reshape(4,1,1) will already force a C-Contiguous copy (and avoids explicite copy thus).

Comment: @Sebastian how would that look as a full answer?

Comment: np.rollaxis(lut, -1)[(np.arange(4).reshape(4,1,1),) + tuple(rgb)]

Comment: If you're going to use `np.arange(4).reshape(4, 1, 1),` why bother rolling lut? Just do `lut[tuple(rgb) + (np.arange(4).reshape(4, 1, 1),)]`.

Comment: In that case the result is not a c-continuous array with the desired end shape.

Comment: @Sebastian, It is when I test it. Is that not true in general?

Comment: Sorry... yeah, nvm I got confused but out shape is of course only depenend on the broadcasting shape, and that is the same in both cases.